# Does a symmetric product of spinor spaces give an irreducible representation of so$(2n+1)$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

The real Lie algebra so$(2n+1,\mathbb{R})$ has an irreducible representation on a vector space $S$ of dimension $2^n$, the spinor representation. For any integer $k>1$, we can consider the induced representation on $\mathrm{Sym}^k S$, the symmetric part of $\otimes^k S$. Is this representation irreducible?

---

I own a copy of *Representation Theory* by Fulton and Harris, but it's mostly example-based and mostly about complex Lie algebras. I didn't find the answer there. (Maybe it's there and I just didn't recognize the way it's expressed.) I've also tried searching online, but I haven't found any freely-accessible resources that address this.